# How can I convert that to MetaWhere or Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, meta-where

Consider a City Model having:

```
  def self.search(field, search)
    if search
      where("#{field} LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

How can I use Arel or Metawhere in that situation knowing that field is a String can have anything like:

"name"
"residents.name"
"state.name"

I want to do something like that (will not work):

```
  def self.search(field, search)
    if search
       where(field =~ "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

So, what are your thoughts?

The real question is, how can I convert that:

"residents.name LIKE '#{value}%'"

To that:

:residents => { :name =~ "#{value}%" }

Comment: It looks like I'll have to go back to SearchLogic. Damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Arel like this.

```
def self.search(field, search)
  if search
    if field =~ /\./ # table and field
      table, field = field.split('.')
      arel_join = table.singularize.camelize.constantize.arel_table
      joins(table.to_sym).where(arel_join[field].matches("%#{search}%"))
    else
      where(Resource.arel_table[field].matches("%#{search}%"))
    end
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

There's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) that does a good job of explaining the basics of using Arel in Rails 3.

Comment: when I have only the first level that works fine. but that: arel_table["residents.name"].matches... doesn't seem to work

Comment: You're right I missed that requirement. I've revised the code above to support passing fields for joined tables. It's not the cleanest code but it should work.

Comment: arel should have that implemented. You can't always count on symbols, specially when the view is responsible for selecting the search parameters.